# Как сделать, чтобы после 30 символов текст скрывался и появлялись 3 точки?

Tags: javascript

Только учусь. Нужно чтобы после ввода 30 символов остальные начали скрываться, и слева добавились 3 точки(...). В HTML ничего нет, кроме подключения скрипта. Если нельзя такое в `prompt` провернуть, то хотя бы в консоль это всё.

```
var input = prompt("Строку введите");
function getInfo (text) {
    console.log(text.trim());
    var i = text.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && text.length > 30) {
        --i; 
    }
}
getInfo(input);
```

Comment: Можно воспользоваться средствами css, свойство text-overflow со значением ellipsis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то для этого `JS` не нужен. Делается через свойство `CSS` `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

```css
.content div
{
 width:150px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 color:transparent;
}
.content div::after
{
 content:attr(title);
 position:absolute;
 top:0;left:0;right:0;
 color:#000;
 white-space:nowrap;
 text-overflow:ellipsis;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
 <div title="Местоположение находится на окраине">Местоположение находится на окраине</div>
</div>
```

В prompt нельзя такое провернуть. Но возможно, что вы хотите, чтобы эти точки были в HTML input-элементе? Если да, то тогда нужен JS.

Comment: Да, но к сожалению этот способ работает только когда текст не более 1 строки.

Answer (score 2):

Можно как уже отвечено - через CSS.
Если нужно именно через JS, то вот:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('#str');
let str = 'It is my long text';

if(str.length > 10) {
  str = str.substr(0, 10) + '...';
}

div.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id='str'></div>
```